# How to query specific column name from multiple table from SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to query the column_name=object_no in the multiple tables ( up to 100 tables). I'm using Oracle SQL Developer.

To shows the tables that do not have column_name=object_no, I tried with the SQL query below.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE NOT COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%OBJECT_NO%'
ORDER BY COLUMN_ID;
```

However, it show the same table multiple times and mixed up with the table that also have `COLUMN_ID='OBJECT_NO'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `user_tab_columns` has `table_name` and `column_name` in each rows, so your select only omit the row with that columns, not other rows with other columns of that table.

One query you could use is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table_name
FROM user_tab_columns c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM user_tab_columns
    WHERE column_name LIKE '%OBJECT_NO%'
        AND table_name = c.table_name
) 
ORDER BY table_name;
```

Other way could work is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table_name
FROM user_tab_columns 
WHERE table_name NOT IN (
    SELECT table_name
    FROM user_tab_columns
    WHERE column_name LIKE '%OBJECT_NO%'
) 
ORDER BY table_name;
```

Comment: thank you so much. both solution is work perfectly for me. !

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
FROM 
    USER_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE 
    TABLE_NAME NOT IN 
    (
        SELECT 
            TABLE_NAME
        FROM 
             USER_TAB_COLUMNS
        WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%OBJECT_NO%'
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
SET SERVEROUT ON;

BEGIN

FOR R IN (SELECT 'SELECT '||A.COLUMN_NAME||' FROM '||A.TABLE_NAME||' ' AS QRY FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS A
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'OBJECT_NO')
LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE USING R.QRY;
END LOOP;
/
```